# my search engine is not responding in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-10.1, tin, search

I am unable to use the search engine in ArcMap. I am trying to create a TIN but when I type TIN (Triangulated irregular networking) into the search space ArcMap doesn't respond.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot